# web graphic editing

Tags: website-design, transparency, background

I have this web image design issue. Hopefully this is the right place to post my question?

i-top-nav-original.png is the original image putting inside the html
[image: the original image]

when load up mixing with other html, it preview nicely.

[image: image shown correctly]

I want to remove the 2 word after the `<`

so I open up windows paint > use eraser to rub out this 2 word
Save it

Then I open again the html page to load it the edited image
However now it become not the same anymore...

[image: image not shown correctly]

Not too sure what causing this, how to properly remove the word while preserve the original background?
need advice from designer.

Answer (score 1):

manage to find the answer myself.  It caused by windows paint don't have preserve transparent ability when save as png.   Initially i didn't realize because when save the same image after editing, it won't prompt warning of original transparency will gone. Till I use "Save As" then the warning come out, then I found out it was limitation of the windows paint software itself....

Comment: Amongst the many reasons MS Paint is not the choice of professionals ;)